# add down icon to multi select for chosenjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I've been struggling with this for a bit. The single select for ChosenJs has a drop down arrow (which comes from the background CSS property on it if you inspect the element)  the multiselect does not.

I have a requirement to add the drop down icon to the multiselect. I would prefer to not manipulate the CSS file that comes with ChosenJs. I would prefer a jQuery/Javascript solution but I can't quite seem to get it.

```js
$('.chosen-select').chosen({

}).change(function(obj, result) {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">

<div>
  <p>
    no html down icon on multi select
  </p>
  <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Any">[Any]</option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
  </select>
  <p>
    html down icon on single select
  </p>

  <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" style="width: 350px;" tabindex="4">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Any">[Any]</option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge you have to manipulate CSS and even on the single select the arrow is drawn differently in different browsers so if you manipulate multi you will probably want to change the css for single too.

Comment: well I believe chosen does not actually use a select for the multi select, instead is an input type of text. you can run the code snippet and inspect the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit of font awesome, some jQuery and Viola!

```js
$('.chosen-select').chosen({

}).change(function(obj, result) {

});

$('<li><i class="fa fa-angle-down" /></li>').css({position: "absolute", right: "10px", top: "5px" }).appendTo('ul.chosen-choices');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div>
  <p>
    no html down icon on multi select
  </p>
  <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Any">[Any]</option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
  </select>
  <p>
    html down icon on single select
  </p>

  <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" style="width: 350px;" tabindex="4">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Any">[Any]</option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
  </select>
</div>
```